# Rally query with multiple filters not working

Tags: javascript, rally

I am trying to query Rally with multiple filters.  I am looking to query Rally for all defects in a specific project that have defects with a specific CreationDate.  When I send the query, I get 0 results back.  I know that there have been defects created in that project on that specific day.  When I send the query with just the project (and get rid of the date filter), I get all the defects that are currently in that project.  I just can't seem to figure out how to query with multiple filters.

```
var data_length;
var filter = [];
var newDate = Rally.util.DateTime.format(new Date('05/10/2013'), 'M d, Y');
filter.push({
    property: 'Project',
    operator: '=',
    value: "/project/7579240995"
});
filter.push({
    property: 'CreationDate',
    operator: '=',
    value: newDate
});
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
    context: { project: null },
    autoLoad: true,
    limit: 10000,
    model: 'Defect',
    fetch: [ 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'Project', 'State', 'Severity', 'CreationDate'],
    filters: filter,
    listeners: {
        load: function( store, data, success ) {
            data_length = data.length;
        }
    }
});
```

Any thoughts or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's the format of your date.  The WSAPI expects all dates to be in the ISO format:

```
filter.push({
    property: 'CreationDate',
    operator: '=',
    value: '2013-05-10'
});
```

Comment: Even after changing the date to use the ISO format, I am still getting 0 results.  Do you happen to know if time matters when querying with dates?  I can't figure out why this would not work.  Any other thoughts that might help?

Comment: You're right.  I think the time is what is breaking it.  Something like this might work: ((CreationDate >= 2013-05-10T00:00:00Z) AND (CreationDate < 2013-05-11T00:00:00Z)).  You will probably want to change the Z to be your current timezone offset.